# Triton inference server serving TorchScript model

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, tensorflow-serving, tensorrt

I am trying to serve a TorchScript model with the triton (tensorRT) inference server. But every time I start the server it throws the following error:

```
PytorchStreamReader failed reading zip archive: failed finding central directory
```

My folder structure is :

```
<model_repository> 
  <model_name>
   config.pbtxt
   <1>
    <model.pt>
```

My config.pbtxt file is :

```
name: "model"
platform: "pytorch_libtorch"
max_batch_size: 1

input[
{
name: "INPUT__0"
data_type:  TYPE_FP32
dims: [-1,3,-1,-1]
}
]

output:[
{
name: "OUTPUT__0"
data_type:  TYPE_FP32
dims: [-1,1,-1,-1]
}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. It was a silly mistake on my part. The `.pt` torchscript file was not loaded properly.